# Unresolved External Symbol with a particular function in c++

Tags: c++, external, symbols

I got the error message like the following:

> Unresolved External Symbol error with calculatewinner Candidate

Here is my code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <fstream>
#include <iomanip>
using namespace std;

void headerforelection();
void getNamecalculatetotal(ifstream& in, string candidates[], double Votes[], double percentvotes[]);
void getNamecalculatetotal2(ifstream& in, string fname[], double Votes[], double percentvotes[]);
void allvotes(double []);
void Votesrecievedpercentage(ifstream& in, char Candidate[], double Votes[], string fname[], double percentvotes[]);
void Votesrecievedpercentage2(double Votes[], string fname[], double percentvotes[]);
void calculatewinner(string fname[], double Votes[]);
void headerforelection();

int main()
{

    ifstream in = ifstream();
    in.open("Votes.txt");
    ofstream out = ofstream();
    out.open("outputs.txt");

    char winner();
    char Candidate();
    string fname[5];
    double Votes[5];
    double percentvotes[5];
    double total = double();
    headerforelection();
    while (!in.eof())
    {


    getNamecalculatetotal(in, fname, Votes, percentvotes);


    Votesrecievedpercentage2(Votes, fname, percentvotes);
    }
    allvotes(Votes);
    calculatewinner(fname, Votes);

}

void getNamecalculatetotal(ifstream& in, string fname[], double Votes[], double percent[])
{

    double total = double();
        for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++)

        {

            in >> fname[i] >> Votes[i];

            total = total + Votes[i];
        }
        for (int j = 0; j < 5; j++)
        {
            percent[j] = (Votes[j] / total) * 100;
        }
    }
    void headerforelection()
    {
        std::cout << fixed << setfill(' ') << left << setw(10) << "Candidate"
            << right << setw(20) << setprecision(0) << "votes Recieved"
            << right << setw(20) << setprecision(2) << "% of Total Votes" << std::endl;
        std::cout << endl;
    }

    void Votesrecievedpercentage2( double Votes[], string fname[], double percentvotes[])

    {
        for (int b = 0; b < 5; b++)
        {
            std::cout << fixed << setfill(' ') << left << setw(10) << fname[b]
                << right << setw(16) << setprecision(0) << Votes[b]
                << right << setw(16) << setprecision(2) << percentvotes << std::endl;


        }
    }
    void allvotes(double Votes[])

    {
        double total = double();
        for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++)
        {
            total = total + Votes[i];
        }
        std::cout << setfill(' ') << left << setw(22) << "Total" << setprecision(0) << total << std::endl;
    }
    void calculatewinner(string fname[], double Votes[])
    {
        {
            int winner = 0;
            for (int l = 0; l, 5; l++)
            {
                if (Votes[l] > Votes[winner])
                {
                    winner = l;//3

                }
            }
        }
        char winner();
        char Candidate();

        std::cout << std::endl;
        std::cout << Candidate << "Is The Winner" << fname << "." << std::endl;
    }
```

Comment: what are you trying to do with this line: `char Candidate();`?

Comment: `ifstream in = ifstream();` this kind of assignment ist completely wrong. To initialize an inputstream, use `ifstream in("Votes.txt");` and sames goes for the output stream.

Answer (score 0):

First to answer your question, change these lines

```
char winner();
char Candidate();
```

everywhere in your code (in `main` as well as in `calculatewinner`) to the following:

```
char winner;
char Candidate;
```

By adding the paranthesis you are actually declaring a prototype to a function. Since you never define a function `Candidate(void)` the linker complains about the missing implementation. This would apply to `char winner()` also, but since you never use this "variable", the linker isn't concerned about this one.

Otherwise, your code is very broken. I am sure you are just learning C++, but your code is quite inconsistent in naming conventions as well as some other errors that should be addressed before doing something else.